# Block diagonal - multiply each block by one element of another vector

Tags: r, matrix

Supppose I have the following block diagonal matrix:

```
a <- matrix(1:6, 2, 3)
b <- matrix(7:10, 2, 2)
library(magic)
Block <- adiag(a,b)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    3    5    0    0
#[2,]    2    4    6    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    0    7    9
#[4,]    0    0    0    8   10
```

And I need to multiply each block by one part of the following vector. This means the first block "a" times 2 and the block "b" times 1.

```
v1=c(2,1)
```

So that at the end I have:

```
#     [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    2    6    10    0    0
#[2,]    4    8    12    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    0     7    9
#[4,]    0    0    0     8   10
```

How could I do that in the most efficient way?

Comment: `apply(Block, 2, "*", rep(v1, each = 2))` should do this.

Comment: bdiag(a * v1[1], b * v1[2]) is okay.

Comment: Pascal would your answer work if I changed the example with matrices and vector of different dimensions?

Comment: Test with `apply(Block, 2, "*", rep(v1, c(NROW(a),NROW(b))))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until there is a better solution or an improvement of this one.

```
a <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
b <- matrix(7:10, 2, 2)
c <- matrix(9:24, 4, 4)

library(magic)
Block <- adiag(a,b,c)
Block
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
#  [1,]    1    4    7    0    0    0    0    0    0
#  [2,]    2    5    8    0    0    0    0    0    0
#  [3,]    3    6    9    0    0    0    0    0    0
#  [4,]    0    0    0    7    9    0    0    0    0
#  [5,]    0    0    0    8   10    0    0    0    0
#  [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    9   13   17   21
#  [7,]    0    0    0    0    0   10   14   18   22
#  [8,]    0    0    0    0    0   11   15   19   23
#  [9,]    0    0    0    0    0   12   16   20   24

v1 <- c(2,1,4)
apply(Block, 2, "*", rep(v1, c(NROW(a),NROW(b),NROW(c))))
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
#  [1,]    2    8   14    0    0    0    0    0    0
#  [2,]    4   10   16    0    0    0    0    0    0
#  [3,]    6   12   18    0    0    0    0    0    0
#  [4,]    0    0    0    7    9    0    0    0    0
#  [5,]    0    0    0    8   10    0    0    0    0
#  [6,]    0    0    0    0    0   36   52   68   84
#  [7,]    0    0    0    0    0   40   56   72   88
#  [8,]    0    0    0    0    0   44   60   76   92
#  [9,]    0    0    0    0    0   48   64   80   96
```

Or as suggested by Ven Yao in the comments:

```
adiag(a*v1[1], b*v1[2], c*v1[3])
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `bdiag` from `library(Matrix)` (using @Pascal's example).  We place the individual vectors i.e. 'a', 'b', 'c' in a `list` (using `mget`), multiply with corresponding elements of 'v1' using `Map` and wrap with `bdiag`.

```
library(Matrix)
as.matrix(bdiag(Map(`*`,mget(letters[1:3]), v1)))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
# [1,]    2    8   14    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    4   10   16    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    6   12   18    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    7    9    0    0    0    0
# [5,]    0    0    0    8   10    0    0    0    0
# [6,]    0    0    0    0    0   36   52   68   84
# [7,]    0    0    0    0    0   40   56   72   88
# [8,]    0    0    0    0    0   44   60   76   92
# [9,]    0    0    0    0    0   48   64   80   96
```